# Can't save custom connector configuration

Tags: microsoft-teams

I am following the tutorials on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/tabs/tabs-configuration with the configuration code provided. When I hit save after some seconds I get the error that it was not successful.

As far as I am concerned all needed valid domains are added.

Manifest.json

```
    {
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/json-schemas/teams/v1.3/MicrosoftTeams.schema.json",
  "manifestVersion": "1.3",
  "id": "ec3e802c-506d-4301-9ae4-868b93461ca0",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "packageName": "com.Package",
  "developer": {
    "name": "Developer",
    "websiteUrl": "https://privateDomain.de",
    "privacyUrl": "https://privateDomain.de",
    "termsOfUseUrl": "https://privateDomain.de"
  },
  "description": {
    "full": "Text",
    "short": "More Text"
  },
  "icons": {
    "outline": "IncomingWebhook.jpg",
    "color": "IncomingWebhook.jpg"
  },
  "connectors": [
    {
      "connectorId": "ec3e802c-506d-4301-9ae4-868b93461ca0",
      "scopes": [
        "team"
      ],
      "configurationUrl": "*linkToConfigurationPage*"
    }
  ],
  "name": {
    "full": "Package",
    "short": "Package"
  },
  "accentColor": "#FFFFFF",
  "validDomains": [
    "bing.com",
    "google.com",
    "*.google.com",
    "*.bing.com",
    "teams-get-started-sample.azurewebsites.net",
    "*.microsoft.com",
    "*.skype.com",
    "*.privateDomain.de",
    "vater-gruppe.de",
    "static2.sharepointonline.com", 
    "secure.aadcdn.microsoftonline-p.com", 
    "code.jquery.com", 
    "statics.teams.microsoft.com", 
    "*.microsoftonline.com", 
    "ajax.googleapis.com"

  ],
  "needsIdentity": "false"
}
```

The code in the index on the SSL capable server(*linkToConfigurationPage*) is

```
`<body>
<form>
  <input type="radio" name="maptype" value="bing" onclick="onClick()"> Bing Maps<br>
  <input type="radio" name="maptype" value="google" onclick="onClick()"> Google Maps
</form> 

<script src="https://statics.teams.microsoft.com/sdk/v1.2/js/MicrosoftTeams.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">  

microsoftTeams.initialize();
microsoftTeams.settings.registerOnSaveHandler(function(saveEvent){

    var radios = document.getElementsByName("maptype");
    if (radios[0].checked) {
       microsoftTeams.settings.setSettings({
         entityId: "bing",
         contentUrl: "https://www.bing.com/maps/embed",
         suggestedDisplayName: "Bing Map",
         websiteUrl: "https://www.bing.com/maps",
         removeUrl: "https://teams-get-started-sample.azurewebsites.net/tabremove.html",
      });
    } else {
       microsoftTeams.settings.setSettings({
         entityId: "google",
         contentUrl: "https://www.google.com/maps/embed",
         suggestedDisplayName: "Google Map",
         websiteUrl: "https://www.google.com/maps",
         removeUrl: "https://teams-get-started-sample.azurewebsites.net/tabremove.html",
      });
    }
    saveEvent.notifySuccess();


});

function onClick() {
    microsoftTeams.settings.setValidityState(true);

}

</script>
</body>
</html>`
```

The error message I get is

```
angular.min.js:112 2018-09-04T09:26:24.007Z Received error from connectors {"seq":1536048346894,"timestamp":1536053183994,"flightSettings":{"Name":"ConnectorFrontEndSettings","AriaSDKToken":"d127f72a3abd41c9b9dd94faca947689-d58285e6-3a68-4cab-a458-37b9d9761d35-7033","SPAEnabled":true,"ClassificationFilterEnabled":true,"ClientRoutingEnabled":true,"EnableYammerGroupOption":true,"EnableFadeMessage":false,"EnableDomainBasedOwaConnectorList":false,"EnableDomainBasedTeamsConnectorList":false,"DevPortalSPAEnabled":true,"ShowHomeNavigationButtonOnConfigurationPage":false},"status":500,"clientType":"SkypeSpaces","connectorType":"ec3e802c-506d-4301-9ae4-868b93461ca0","name":"handleMessageError","nonPIIInfo":"{\"exception\":{}}"}
```

Can anyone help me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Is sideloading enabled for your tenant? If not then could you please ask you tenant Admin to [enable sideloading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/MicrosoftTeams/enable-features-office-365#apps) and try once more?

Comment: I verified that sideloading is turned on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to remove the "validDomains" attribute from the generated mainfest.json.

Comment: Have similar problem - this solution doesn't help

Answer (score 0):

The content URL in *microsoftTeams.settings.setSettings()* is used to [handle edits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/connectors/connectors-creating#handling-edits). This URL also need to be under the same domain which is added in Connector Portal's valid domain section. You could try following as your **linkToConfigurationPage** is already part of valid domains.

```
 microsoftTeams.settings.setSettings({
         entityId: "bing",
         contentUrl: "*linkToConfigurationPage*",
         suggestedDisplayName: "Bing Map"
      })
```

Comment: I added all domains in the Connector Portal and downloaded the mainfest.json again to integrate it into the zip file. I even tried switching all URLs to "*linkToConfigurationPage*". I still get the same error. :(

Comment: Could you please confirm if "h ttps://innervision-ev.org" is added to the valid domains section in connector portal? Note- it should include protocol (https) as well.

Comment: I did just a moment ago. But I had to remove "https://" in the new manifest, because it caused an error. After that I get the same error again. The server uses https only

Comment: Could you please just put "h ttps://innervision-ev.org" (without space) in connector portal? I don't see **"ht tps://innervision-ev.org"** added in the valid domains section in Connector portal for your Connector (ec3e802c-506d-4301-9ae4-868b93461ca0). Please add it, you can remove valid domains section from downloaded manifest file for now.

Comment: The domain was definitely. I don't know why you could not see it. However, removing the validDomains attribute from the manifest.json seems to work. I don't get the error message and the configuration popup closes. Are there any other side effects from removing the validDomains attribute? If not: shouldn't it be removed from the beginning?

Comment: Thanks for your support!