# Microsoft Teams Connector error "ngClickDecorator: value not found in enum type. value:"

Tags: microsoft-teams

I'm currently seeing this error when I try and save my connector configuration:

```
21T21:05:12.087Z ngClickDecorator: value not found in enum type. value:
```

and

```
 21T21:05:12.155Z Received error from connectors {"seq":1611247472155,"timestamp":1611263112143,"flightSettings": {"Name":"ConnectorFrontEndSettings","AriaSDKToken":"d127f72a3abd41c9b9dd94faca947689-d58285e6-3a68-4cab-a458-37b9d9761d35-7033","SPAEnabled":true,"ClassificationFilterEnabled":true,
    "ClientRoutingEnabled":true,"EnableYammerGroupOption":true,
    "EnableFadeMessage":false,"EnableDomainBasedOwaConnectorList":false,
    "EnableDomainBasedTeamsConnectorList":false,"DevPortalSPAEnabled":true,
"ShowHomeNavigationButtonOnConfigurationPage":false,"DisableConnectToO365InlineDeleteFeedbackPage":true},"status":500,"clientType":"SkypeSpaces",
    "connectorType":"c6adb316-46b2-4e46-a511-8b4947b3d554","name":"handleMessageError"}
```

And the SO post: [Can't save custom connector configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52163103/cant-save-custom-connector-configuration) is very close to my problem however I have added my configurationURL to my valid domains, and removed mine from the manifest but with still no luck. I'm all set up on my permissions as well unless there is something specific I am missing to configure?

Any suggestions, below is my manifest and code:
Manifest:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/json-schemas/teams/v1.8/MicrosoftTeams.schema.json",
  "manifestVersion": "1.8",
  "version": "1.0.3",
  "showLoadingIndicator": true,
  "isFullScreen": true,
  "id": "c6adb316-46b2-4e46-a511-8b4947b3d554",
  "packageName": "com.test",
  "developer": {
    "name": "Test, Inc",
    "websiteUrl": "https://test.com",
    "privacyUrl": "https://test.com/privacy",
    "termsOfUseUrl": "https://test.com/toc"
  },
  "icons": {
    "color": "color.png",
    "outline": "outline.png"
  },
  "connectors": [
    {
      "connectorId": "c6adb316-46b2-4e46-a511-8b4947b3d554",
      "scopes": [
        "team"
      ],
      "configurationUrl": "https://localdev-test.test.com/connector"
    }
  ],
  "name": {
  "short": "Test Development",
  "full": "Test for Microsoft Teams"
  },
  "description": {
    "short": "Test Development",
    "full": "Test for Microsoft Teams"
  },
  "accentColor": "#FFFFFF",
  "staticTabs": [
    {
      "entityId": "22f101b6-f9a2-44d3-8eba-74309295f398",
      "scopes": [
        "personal"
      ],
      "context":[
        "personalTab",
        "channelTab"
      ],
      "name": "TestSite",
      "contentUrl": "https://localdev-test.test.com",
      "websiteUrl": "https://localdev-test.test.com",
      "searchUrl":  "https://localdev-test.test.com"
    }
  ],
  "devicePermissions": [
    "notifications",
    "openExternal"
  ],
  "permissions": [
    "identity",
    "messageTeamMembers"
  ]
}
```

Code:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    microsoftTeams.initialize();
    microsoftTeams.settings.registerOnSaveHandler((saveEvent) => {
      microsoftTeams.settings.setSettings({
        entityId: 'Create',
        contentUrl: 'https://localdev-test.test.com/connector',
        removeUrl: 'https://localdev-test.test.com/connector',
        configName: 'Create'
      });

      microsoftTeams.settings.getSettings((settings) => {
        this.webhookUrl = settings.webhookUrl;
        localStorage.setItem('connectorWebHook', this.webhookUrl);
      });

      saveEvent.notifySuccess();
    });
  }

  onClick(): void {
    if (!this.webhookUrl) {
      microsoftTeams.settings.setValidityState(true);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a Microsoft Bug, the "Configuration page for your Connector" on the Connector Portal is immutable (even though it is in an edit field). Meaning that the URL you set on the creation of the Connector can not change through development or you will get this error. So just making a new connector through the portal with my changed configuration URL fixed my problem.

A comment on their git points to this as well: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/msteams-docs/issues/1738#issuecomment-647675420

Comment: Have similar problem - didn't help in my case